# No such module error after copy

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a working Xcode project, with cocoapods. I made a copy of my project to do some testing of new code. This was done to still be able to fix bugs, in the original, that users point out. But after i copied the project i can't build and run it anymore. The issue is a cocoa pod, SearchTextField to be specific, i get the error message 'No such module'.

To clarify, i didn't change any code yet. Just did a copy of the project and tried to run it.

I have done a clean before the build, but it did not help. Also i have reinstalled my pods, that also didn't help.

Why is it that i can't copy my project and run it? Could anybody, at least, point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
I now use the SearchTextField class without importing, by moving the swift file into my project. But now i have the same problem with IDZSwiftCommonCrypto, i think something is seriously wrong with my project. Removing and reinstalling of the pods does nothing.

Now i gradually disabled als imports and it seams like i have the same problem for all my pods. I think Xcode doesn't look at the right place for them, is that possible?

Comment: Have you installed the pods after you copied it?

Comment: All you need to do is reinstall pods.

Comment: nope, installed the pods before. Ok Will try to install them again.

Comment: No that did not help with the issue. Still getting No such module.

Comment: “I made a copy of my project to do some testing of new code. This was done to still be able to fix bugs, in the original, that users point out.” So don’t do that. Isn’t this why God gave us git branches?

Comment: How did you copy?

Comment: And how did you open your project after the copy?

Comment: Are you sure you called 'pod install' in the folder of the copied project and not in the original project?

Comment: well i used gui to copy the project folder, startet the project with the workspace file.  Yes i double checked the folder for the 'pod install'